# python-autologin using selenium

Tags: html, python-3.5

I am trying to write an autologin Python3 script using selenium webdriver in Chrome for *binance.com*. I've reached the point where on submitting the username and the password a slider is shown that should be slidden manually until a puzzle piece is placed in an empty space:

[image: image like this occurs]

The slider changes everytime.

How can i simulate programatically an actual slide?

Comment: This protection is there for a reason.

Comment: Is the puzzle piece the same each time?

Comment: yes puzzle piece changes every time